# Firefox removing screen limit in Responsive Design Mode

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Is it possible to remove the limit of 10000x10000 Pixel for the screen?

I want to take a screenshot of my website of 18000px but firefox has a limit to 10000px.

I search in about:config for the limit settings but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I looked at the correct [code](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/7a9ade6c3861b2206ae1b17d7420e4852e5b231f/devtools/client/responsivedesign/responsivedesign.jsm#L36), then the 10k limit is hardcoded, so I assume there is no way to configure it.

Comment: so i could clone the repo change the limit, compile and run?

Comment: Firefox is open source, so yes, you could modify the file and build the browser yourself. There should be instructions somewhere available. But before you do it, maybe there is another way. If you are working on Windows, then please find in Firefox install directory a file called `omni.ja` located in `browser` folder. You should be able to unpack the file with almost any archive extracting tool. There you'll find in `chrome/devtools/modules/devtools/client/responsivedesign/responsivedesign.jsm` file. Edit it and create the `.ja` file again.

Comment: @SergejAndropov You can find some info on this file type here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/About_omni.ja_(formerly_omni.jar)

Comment: i changed the limits but i think firefox is chaching the files so its still 1000px   but it works when i run firefox with "firefox -purgecaches" :')

Comment: @SergejAndropov, Changing most files within a `omni.ja` can be done with add-ons (at least until Mozilla neuters them by restricting them to WebExtensions only). It does *not* require recompiling Firefox, or unpacking a *omni.ja* and repacking it. I have a [published add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/change-bookmark-recent-folder-) which does *exactly* this (change a parameter defined as a `const` to one which is configured via the add-on's options dialog). Note: I would probably go about building the add-on differently if I was doing it over again. (cont)

Comment: @SergejAndropov, (cont) The above add-on grew out of becoming tired of unpacking and repacking *omni.ja* for each new version of Firefox (and for each version I have installed). That file is accessible from within Firefox at the URL `resource://devtools/client/responsivedesign/responsivedesign.jsm`. [Something strange happens with the above code as delivered by Stack Overflow. A couple of additional non-visible characters are being added. You will need to manually remove them from the URL. Copy&paste works from the code I enter, but not from what SO displays].

Comment: I'm on Firefox 105 and it appears things have changed. I found a `MIN_VIEWPORT_DIMENSION` in `resource://devtools/client/responsive/constants.js`, but so far no luck finding the top limit, which still appears to be 10,000.